# Чем в java заменить множественное наследование?

Tags: java, классы, наследование

Хочу реализовать приблизительно следующую архитектуру:

[image]

#### Пояснение:

- `Base` - Что-то вроде сущности-хранилища, в котором хранятся какие-то базовые объекты;
- `ChildN` - потомки, реализующие свой спектр действий над данными, которые хранятся в классе `Base`. По сути являются интерфейсами, т.к. никакого состояния не хранят;
- `static Mixin` - класс, объединяющий в себе все методы из `ChildN`. Коллизий между именами методов нет. Все его методы (т.е. методы, унаследованные от `ChildN`) должны быть статическими, вызываться без инстанцирования.

В [python](/questions/tagged/python) эта задача легко бы решилась множественным наследованием, в [java](/questions/tagged/java) такого нет. Как быть?

---

#### Примерный псевдокод того, что хочу реализовать:

```java
class Base {
    static protected final String someString = "01";
}

class Child1 extends Base {
    static public char get_0() {
        return someString.charAt(0);
    }
}

class Child2 extends Base {
    static public char get_1() {
        return someString.charAt(1);
    }
}

class MixIn extends Child1, Child2 {  // Так сделать нельзя

}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MixIn.get_0());  // Итоговое использование должно быть таким
        System.out.println(MixIn.get_1());
    }
}
```

Comment: В Java есть понятие interface, вы можете свои Child классы реализовать с их помощью. Множественное наследование интерфейсов допустимо

Comment: у всех Ваших классов будет один общий предок. И тут возникает целый спектр разных проблем. Поэтому в Java и решили отказаться от этого. Но можно делать множественное "наследование" от интерфейсов. А у интерфейсов теперь есть "имплементация методов":)

Comment: Если `Base` - хранилище, используйте композицию. Использование наследования здесь будет семантически неверно, т.к. наследование классов, выполняющих операции над данными, от класса `Base`, не представляет отношение *IS-A*

Comment: Все было понятно пока не появились статические методы. Вы просто так добавили static? Для статических методов наследование здесь имеет мало смысла. Почему нельзя написать `Child1.get_0()` и `Child2.get_1()` если методы не переопределяются все равно? Может доработаете пример чтобы было понятнее что именно Вам нужно?

Comment: Возможно, паттерн стратегия подойдет. Классы ChildN выполняют только действия, поэтому их вполне можно заменить на стратегии.

Comment: @defaultlocale Во "внешний мир" должен уходить класс только со статическими методами, все эти биения на классы и mix-in'ы для удобства разработки, чтобы знать, что определенный потомок делает определенные действия над общими данными.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как выяснилось, разделение функционала на несколько классов с повторным объединением в один нужно вам исключительно в целях логической группировки. Возможные решения вашей проблемы:

---

### Использование интерфейсов

Вы можете сделать `child-ы` интерфейсами. В Java нет множественно наследования, зато можно имплементировать несколько интерфейсов. Чтобы сделать реализацию методов прямо в интерфейсах *(чтобы они не требовали реализации в реализующем их классе)*, можно использовать ключевое слово `default`:

```
class Base {
    static public final String str = "01";
}

interface Child1 {
    default char get0() {
        return Base.str.charAt(0);
    }
}

interface Child2 {
    default char get1() {
        return Base.str.charAt(1);
    }
}

class MixIn implements Child1, Child2 {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MixIn mixIn = new MixIn();
        System.out.println(mixIn.get0());
        System.out.println(mixIn.get1());
    }
}
```

### Отказ от разделения функционала

Вы работаете с одним репозиторием Base. На мой взгляд здесь более чем достаточно использование одного класса без всяких интерфейсов. Более того, можно все эти методы разместить в классе Base.

Например:

```
class Base {
    private final String str = "01";

    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }
}

class MixIn {
    private Base base;

    public MixIn(Base base) {
        this.base = base;
    }

    public char get0() {
        return base.getStr().charAt(0);
    }

    public char get1() {
        return base.getStr().charAt(1);
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MixIn mixIn = new MixIn(new Base());
        System.out.println(mixIn.get0());
        System.out.println(mixIn.get1());
    }
}
```

### Использование статических внутренних классов

Вы говорите, что вам нужна логическая группировка. В Java существует конструкция, которая называется статический внутренний или вложенный класс. Внутри класса создаётся ещё один класс, который отмечается `static`. Таким образом вы можете достичь логической группировки. Пример:

```
class Base {
    static public final String someString = "01";
}

class MixIn {
    public static class Child1 {
        static char get1() {
            return Base.someString.charAt(1);
        }
    }

    public static class Child2 {
        static char get0() {
            return Base.someString.charAt(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Видите, я создал общий класс MixIn, а внутри него два статических класса. Вызываются они вот так:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(MixIn.Child1.get1());
        System.out.println(MixIn.Child2.get0());
    }
}
```

Как видите, никакого инстанцирование нет, а классы/методы логически сгруппированы.

Comment: Нужно это для того, чтобы как раз в `MixIn` классе не были перечислены все методы. Я хочу логически разбить методы по разным сущностям, а в `MixIn` их все "объединить". Как результат должен быть `MixIn` класс с кучей статических методов, но хочется избежать, чтобы в *коде* все эти методы были перечислены в одном классе. Ради этого и необходимо разбиение методов по разным сущностям, а в `MixIn` иметь "слияние" методов из этих сущностей. Класс-хранилище, к слову, тоже статический, в нём всё объявлено, как `static final`.

Comment: По Вашему первому примеру получаю `non-static method get_0() cannot be referenced from a static context`. Oracle JDK8, если имеет значение.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов моя ошибка в синтаксисе. Исправил ответ

Comment: Т.е., инстанс всё равно надо создавать :( В `MixIn`, по идее, всё контекстно-независимое (т.е., статическое) и я не вижу смысла создавать инстанс класса, если от него нужны только статические методы.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов можно без инстанса, но тогда надо уже в MixIn создать статические методы, которые будут вызывать методы интерфейсов-родителей. Причём им не надо в таком случае быть родителями.

Comment: Но в таком случае опять получится, что в `MixIn` классе будут перечислены все методы явно.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов ну... Согласно ООП вы создаёте объект, который имеет конкретную цель. У вас есть репозиторий Base. И логично создать объект, который будет работать с репозиторием Base. MixIn например. Я не вижу логики в разделении работы с одним и тем же репозиторием на три класса, чтобы потом всё равно объединить это в один класс.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов В Java вы можете создавать статические внутренние (их называют вложенными) классы, они как раз служат для такой вот логической группировки. В чём суть: вы объявляете класс и объявляете внутри него ещё классы. Так сразу понятно, что к чему. Я сейчас дополню свой ответ примером, вы увидите.

Comment: @МихаилМуругов я дополнил свой ответ примером.